# `bower install` does nothing inside putty instance

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, putty, bitnami

I'm trying to set up my project in Amazon ec2 instance. I'm using Bitnami as AMI. Everything worked well except `bower install`. It's not even throwing any kind of error. When I do simply `bower` it shows the commands list etc. I tried some solutions suggested online related to Node.js and NPM, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. `bower install -f` solved the issue